# Gitlab codeowers from different parent group

Tags: gitlab

I'm new to Gitlab and was wondering if you can set a CODEOWNERS file to point to a different parent group.  When I tried the below CODEOWNERS setting the group members do not show.  I wasn't sure if this supported by GitLab.

[image: codeowners-diff-parent]